# Google script, how to create a script to link multiple spreadsheets based on their id's?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization

I know my title is vague but I couldn't think of a better title for it.

I'm attempting to create a script that connects a central master spreadsheet with 50 sheets within it to 50 individual spreadsheets where each one is a copy of one of the sheets on the master spreadsheet.

My progress so far is that I now have a script where the changes from one sheet copy over to another spreadsheet with a specific ID, using the name of the sheet as a shared value but you can see that multiple problems come up immediately:

1. When the names of the sheets change which they will need to do the link no longer works (already solved: credits to cooper)
2. Each of the individual files has its own individual IDs and I would need some way to reference each of them (my current idea for this is some kind of function that creates a 2d array of all of the IDs of the other spreadsheets in a folder as the first row and the second row is the names of the sheets in those spreadsheets and then you could put this function into my current script that I have to link two spreadsheets)

my current code (credits to Cooper)

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id-of-the-other-sheet');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart);
  rg.setValue(e.value);
}
```

Thanks in Advance for all of your help, I know that this is quite a large project but all contributions are welcome.

:)

Comment: Welcome. Take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve]. Titles should be descriptive of the problem. Your question should include a statement of a single problem. And in most cases you should include the code you have written to try to solve the problem.

Comment: +1 @Cooper. Regarding your issue#1, if you can't control this, then you do not have the corporate (or other authority) to undertake you task. You may as well give up now. Regarding issue #2, your suggestion of a list of spreadsheet IDs sounds perfectly reasonable to me. To be honest, I don't see that you have a programming problem here. Perhaps you might show us some of your code.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks you very for your response, as I am doing a degree right now I don't have a great amount of time to sink into this and right now is quite busy for me, but I will attempt to write and test something by the end of wednesday.

Comment: @Cooper I very much understand where you are coming from but if you look at this from my point of view I still don't understand the second lot of code that you wrote me so I couldn't have written it myself, I'm not asking for someone to write it for me (nice as that is) but suggestions and opinions on my ideas and your own ideas are very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## Project Scaling

The installable total trigger run time for G Suite Free Edition is 3 hours. So that works out to be about 3.6 minutes per spreadsheet.

I did some measurements and I got an average execution time of 0.4263 seconds. So at 3.6 minutes * 60 seconds per minute / 0.4263 seconds per operation that is a little over 500 edits per day per spreadsheet.  I suppose that might actually work.

On a G Suite Business account that would be over 1000 edits per day per spreadsheet.

I look forward to seeing some of your code.

Comment: Props for that calculation. Spreadsheet are workhorses; capable of many tasks, including ones for which it was never designed. On SO there are examples of making sheets jump through hoops that designers never imagined. But there is a point where it is not the best tool for managing data and this must come close. 50 people sharing data suggests a database, not a spreadsheet. I realise that Google spreadsheets are free and Google databases are not (or not necessarily). But there are real, financial costs of maintaining free spreadsheet systems that could/would fund a database.

Comment: @Cooper I've written my code, how can I send it to you?

Comment: it's  not necessary.  I've written some of my own.  I have an example running with 5 spreadsheets.  I needed it so that I could calculate the operations per day.  I don't think there's any problem with the satellite stations but the master spreadsheet could be interesting with 50 simultaneous users.  I remember one of the previous comments on another question was that  30 simultaneous users is about the max for GoogleScript.